# Possible to get HtmlNode's position & length within original input?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

Consider the following HTML fragment (`_` is used for whitespace):

```
<head>
    ...
    <link ... ___/>
    <!-- ... -->
    ...
</head>
```

I'm using Html Agility Pack (HAP) to read HTML files/fragments and to strip out links. What I want to do is find the `LINK` (and some other) elements and then replace them with whitespace, like so:

```
<head>
    ...
    ____________
    <!-- ... -->
    ...
</head>
```

The parsing part seems to be working so far, I get the nodes I'm looking for. However, HAP tries to fix the HTML content while I need everything to be *exactly* the same, except for the changes I'm trying to make. Plus, HAP seems to have quite a few bugs when it comes to writing back content that was read in previously, so the approach I want to take is let HAP parse the input and then I go back to the original input and replace content that I don't want.

The problem is, `HtmlNode` doesn't seem to have an input length property. It has `StreamPosition` which seems to indicate where reading of the node's content started within the input but I couldn't find a length property that'd tell me how many characters were consumed to build the node.

I tried using the `OuterHtml` propety but, unfortunately, HAP tries to fix the `LINK` by removing the `___/` part (a `LINK` element is not supposed to be closed). Because of this, `OuterHtml.Length` returns the wrong length.

Is there a way in HAP to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up modifying the code of HtmlAgilityPack to expose a new property that returns the private `_outerlength` field of `HtmlNode`.

```
public virtual int OuterLength
{
    get
    {
        return ( _outerlength );
    }
}
```

This seems to be working fine so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve the same result without recompiling HAP, then use reflection to access the private variable.

I usually wouldn't recommend reflection to access private variables, but I recently had the exact same situation as this and used reflection, because I was unable to use a recompiled version of the assembly.  To do this, create a static variable that holds the field info object (to avoid recreating it on every use):

```
private static readonly FieldInfo HtmlNodeOuterLengthFieldInfo = typeof(HtmlNode).GetField("_outerlength", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Then whenever you want to access the true length of the original outer HTML:

```
var match = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("xpath");
var htmlLength = (int)HtmlNodeOuterLengthFieldInfo.GetValue(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Transformed @Xcalibur's answer into an extension method.

Note that `HtmlNode` has property `OuterLength`, but it isn't the same as it's private field `_outerlength`, which is what we need. (Reading other answers here I first thought that since 2013, HtmlAgilityPack already added the `OuterLength` as a public property, which they did, but after some testing I noticed it simply returns length of `OuterHtml`). So we can either rebuild the package from source to expose the field as a public property, or use an extension method with Reflection (which is slow).

### Extension method

```
namespace HtmlAgilityPack
{
    public static class HtmlDocumentExtensions
    {
        private static readonly System.Reflection.FieldInfo HtmlNodeOuterLengthFieldInfo = 
          typeof(HtmlNode).GetField("_outerlength", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
          | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        public static int GetOuterLengthInStream(this HtmlNode node) => 
          (int)HtmlNodeOuterLengthFieldInfo.GetValue(node ?? 
          throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)));
    }
}
```

Because `HtmlNode` already has property `OuterLength`, to avoid ambiguity I called the method `GetOuterLengthInStream()`.

### Usage

```
node.GetOuterLengthInStream()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But for some reason sometimes this value is negative, same for _innerlength