# Get end of element with HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack to parse my HTML, and I need to know the position of each element within the HTML. `HtmlNode.StreamPosition` gives me the location in the HTML, works great. However, I'd also like the stream position of the *end* of element. I can get the `StreamPosition` and add on the length of the `OuterHTML`, but this is inaccurate as the `OuterHTML` from HTMLAgility pack will often not match up exactly with the actual HTML text.

I'm also game for using AngleSharp, if it's any easier or better suited to this. So basically, I can get the location of the start of a HTML element, how can I get the location of the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a private **_endnode** field of HtmlNode which is the closing tag of element. So either you can change HAP source code to expose it, or you can use System.Reflection to access it.

There is another 
[similar HAP issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861994/possible-to-get-htmlnodes-position-length-within-original-input) with some example codes.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've worked around for the moment, but I might return to it and use Reflection to get at it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't need `_endnode` field, `_outerlength` field would be enough calculate the end position of a node